# fontawesomefx issue with Scene Builder

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8, font-awesome

When I import fontawesomefx-commons.jar (version 8.15) into Scene Builder and run JAR analysis, I get these errors:

```
Exception for: de/jensd/fx/glyphs/GlyphIcon.class
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:2

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1012)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:105)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:298)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runWatching(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:192)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphIcon
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1010)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphIcon.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2971)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:403)
    ... 13 more


Exception for: de/jensd/fx/glyphs/GlyphIcons.class
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:2

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1012)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:105)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:298)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runWatching(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:192)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphIcons
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1010)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphIcons.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2971)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:403)
    ... 13 more


Exception for: de/jensd/fx/glyphs/GlyphsBuilder.class
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:2

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1012)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:105)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:298)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runWatching(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:192)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphsBuilder
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1010)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphsBuilder.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2971)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:403)
    ... 13 more


Exception for: de/jensd/fx/glyphs/GlyphsFactory.class
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:2

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1012)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:105)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:298)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runWatching(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:192)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphsFactory
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1010)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphsFactory.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2971)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:403)
    ... 13 more


Exception for: de/jensd/fx/glyphs/GlyphsStyle.class
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:2

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1012)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:105)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:298)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runWatching(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:192)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphsStyle
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1010)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphsStyle.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2971)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:403)
    ... 13 more


Exception for: de/jensd/fx/glyphs/GlyphStackIcon.class
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:2

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1012)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:105)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:298)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runWatching(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:192)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1010)
    ... 11 more


Exception for: de/jensd/fx/glyphs/GlyphStackIcons.class
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:2

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1012)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:105)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:298)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runWatching(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:192)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphStackIcons
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1010)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphStackIcons.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2971)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:403)
    ... 13 more
```

Does anyone know why that may be happening. I added the dependencies to the POM in my project and when I set the icon from code it works. I'd like to do it via Scene Builder so i can see the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like SceneBuilder expects `GlyphIcon` to provide a no-args constructor but the class for that particular versions defines a constructor that takes at least one argument.

Ikonli (http://aalmiray.github.io/ikonli/) delivers similar behavior as FontAwesomeFX but with more icons.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I removed the fontawesomefx jars and added ikonli jars to Scene Builder and I am getting similar behaviour:

Exception for: org/kordamp/ikonli/javafx/FontIcon.class
java.io.IOException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/kordamp/ikonli/Ikon
 at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:109)
 at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)
 at

Comment: After I added ikonli-core to Scene Builder as well, it worked. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Right. Ikonli follows a modular design and targets both Swing and JavaFX. Once you've picked the -core and -javafx deps you only need to select which icon packs to use :-)